# Why does Sequelize "include / attributes" won't work with findAll and findOne requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm working on an API communicating with MySQL via Sequelize.
I'm dealing with users and their publications. This works perfectly fine, I can cerate users and publications with userId associated. But now I want to get the name of the user who did the publication, and not just the userId.

So I work with associations between my models 'Users' and 'Publications'. I've defined the associations in my sequelize models and migration files but when I add to my controller :

```
            model : User,
            attributes: ['firstName']
        }],
```

I get an error 400 with no details.

If I only write "model : user" without attributes it does not work either so I guess it cannot find the model User.

I followed the steps explained by Sequelize manual, tried to compare with other github examples and it seems ok in theory. I spent two days trying to changes character case, I tried many options given by sequelize [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html), I dropped all my tables and recreated them but I'm running in circles now :-)

Below my migration files and models.
Thanks for your help !

**Controller for Publications**

```
const models = require('../models');        // importation des modèles sequelize
const Publication = models.publication;
const User = models.user;

exports.getAllPublications = (req, res, next) => {
    Publication.findAll({
        include: [{
            model : User,
            attributes: ['firstName']
        }],
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
    })

    .then(        
        (publications) => {        
            res.status(200).json(publications);
        }
    ).catch(
        (error) => {
            res.status(400).json({   
                error: error
            });
        }
    );
};
```

**User Sequelize model**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
      static associate(models) {
        models.User.hasMany(models.Publication)

      }
    };

  User.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    isAdmin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

**Publication Sequelize model**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Publication extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.Publication.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: {
      
          allowNull: false,
        }
        });
    }
  };
  
  Publication.init({
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Publication',
  });
  return Publication;
};
```

**Index**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
require('dotenv').config()               // importation dotenv pour sécuriser passwords
const db = {};


let sequelize;
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME, 
    process.env.DB_USER, 
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,  {

      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT
  });

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);


    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.user = require("./user.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.publication = require("./publication.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.comment = require("./comment.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)

module.exports = db
```

**Publication migration file**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Publications', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      title: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        len: [2,50]
      },
      content: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING(1234),
        len: [2,1000]
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Publications');
  }
};
```

**User creation controller**

```
exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {
    
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)    // On crypte le mot de passe (algorithme exécuté 10 fois) / asynchrone
  
        .then(hash => {   
          console.log(hash)
            const newUser = User.create({           // modèle sequelize
              lastName : req.body.lastName,
              firstName : req.body.firstName,
              email: req.body.email,
              password: hash,                  // On enregistre le mdp crypté plutôt que le mdp simple
             
              })
              

        .then((newUser )=> res.status(201).json({ message: 'created' })) // Requête traitée avec succès et création d’un document
        .catch(error => 
          res.status(400).json({ error })); // Bad Request*/
        
      })
    .catch(error => { 
      console.log("erreur 500")
      res.status(500).json({ error })}); // Erreur interne du serveur
  };
```

**New App.js after changing models as recommended**

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');         // importation application Express
require('dotenv').config()                  // importation dotenv pour sécuriser passwords
const mysqlTable = process.env.MYSQLTABLE;
const mysqlUsername = process.env.MYSQLUSERNAME;     
const mysqlPassword = process.env.MYSQLPASSWORD; 
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  // importation fonction body parser pour extraction objet json de la demande
const cors = require('cors');               // module CORS
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize'); // importation application Sequelize pour communiquer avec MySQL
    
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');   // Importation routeur users
const publicationRoutes = require('./routes/publication');   // Importation routeur posts
const commentRoutes = require('./routes/comment');   // Importation routeur posts

const Publication = require('./models/publication');
const User = require('./models/user')
Publication.belongsTo(User, { Constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
User.hasMany(Publication);

const sequelize = new Sequelize(mysqlTable, mysqlUsername, mysqlPassword, { // Connexion à la base de données mySQL
  host : 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
  })

const app = express();      // application Express
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Enregistrement body parser
app.use(cors());            // module CORS
app.use(limiter);           // rate limit

app.use((req, res, next) => {  // Ajout headers pour résoudre les erreurs CORS
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // accéder à notre API depuis n'importe quelle origine
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization'); // ajouter les headers mentionnés aux requêtes envoyées vers notre API
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'); // envoyer des requêtes avec les méthodes mentionnées 
    next();
  });


app.use('/api/auth', userRoutes)      // Enregistrement routeur users
app.use('/api/publication', publicationRoutes)    // Enregistrement routeur publications
app.use('/api/comment', commentRoutes)    // Enregistrement routeur publications
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from our exchange of comments, the problem comes from the declaration of associations.

Personally I don't like associations to be defined like what you have done (I didn't say it's incorrect!), personally I do it like following.

I create an instance of Sequelize under a specific file (for example, under ./util/database.js):

**database.js**:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'user_name', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  storage: "./session.mysql",
  host: 'localhost'
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I define my models like this:

**User model**:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
  isAdmin: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
});

module.exports = User;
```

**Publication model**:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const Publication = sequelize.define('publication', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      title: Sequelize.STRING,
      content: Sequelize.STRING
    });
    
    module.exports = Publication;
```

Then, I define the associations in the **app.js** file:

```
Publication.belongsTo(User, { Constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
User.hasMany(Publication);
```

To be sure that the new database's schema is well integrated, I use the `sync` method with `force` attribute (just for the first time, then you should delete this attribute and just use the sync method)

```
// this will run on starting the server
sequelize
  .sync({ force: true }) // run it just in the first time after changing the database, this command will re-draw the database
  // .sync()
  .then(() => app.listen(8080))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And finally, you can keep what you have done to fetch the data, and also you can do something like this:

```
User.findByPk(userId, {include: ['publications']})

//supposing that you have an instance of a User (user)
user.getPublications({})
user.getPublications({where: { id: publicationId }})
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad ! I tried this too but same error. The simple : [{
            model : User}] should work too if I understand correctly the manual....

Comment: @GeffSwayze, can you tell me what you get by doing just: include: ["User"] ?

Comment: I don't get anyhting. If I remove it I get "Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `userId`, `title`, `content`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Publications` AS `Publication` ORDER BY `Publication`.`createdAt` DESC;"

Comment: Great, so the problems comes from the association itself, I will edit my answer and show you another way (my preferred way) to do associations. Please wait until I finish up my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it's really nice of you !!!

Comment: thx for the eidt i will try it right now and keep you posted !

Comment: No need to specify through options inside include here. Through is necessary in many-to-many associated tables for limiting junction table's attributes.

Comment: @EzizHudayberdiyev, I rechecked the manual, and YES, you are right. I will update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA when I declare const Publication and User I have the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined". I imported sequelize from index.js file though- const sequelize = require('./index');  Am I missing something ?

Comment: @GeffSwayze sequelize is just an instance of Sequelize, to help you I will update my answer showing you how to define it.

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA thx, sorry if my question is basic but I'm a bit lost here

Comment: @GeffSwayze dont worry, its totally normal :)

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA i followed the steps, now none of my controllers work (without "include"); When I try to create a user I get a 500 error. Should I modify something in the index and migration files too (code included in the initial question). Thx !

Comment: @GeffSwayze I need more details about the error you got..

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I had nothin specific i'm gonna try to find more details

Comment: @GeffSwayze, its not too complecated, just do some console.log in different way to see what is not good !

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA yup, I'm trying to solve other issues and i'll send you that right after, thanks again for your kind help

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I added the user controller at the end of the question. I did a console.log on all elemtns of the request and they're all ok. The problem seems to be at "User.create" level (It worked before all the database modifs). To be able to start the server I hade to mute these three lines in index.js db.user = require("./user.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.publication = require("./publication.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.comment = require("./comment.js")(sequelize, Sequelize) cf index.js in question body too...

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I also added the app.js to have a global view !

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I've just realized I've created the field userId directly in my Publication model, but I guess the association should take care of it througn my publication controller ?

Comment: @GeffSwayze where you define your server ? (i.e., the app.listen(...)) ?

Comment: I dont have experience with migrations, but I guess you can ignore migration and use the sync() method of sequelize (see my post's update)

Comment: concerning the userId, did you follow exactly the same schema wich I have suggested in my answer ? Because yes, the userId will be managed automaticly and no need to create it manually.

Comment: I see nowhere where you show me the logs ? We need to debug the application, so I don't see any singe of where the app is crashed. Please add some logs and tell me what you get for every log.

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I restarted from scractch to be sur I did as you explained. I added the sync in app.js too. I have a brand new error in my index file that crashes the server (there was no error with thsi line before) => const model = new(require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes));
TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: I can not see where you did the 'const model = new(require...' ?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA in  ".forEach(file => {" at the end of the index.js in the model directory (in the question body)

Comment: I can not understand why you disturbing yourself by handling manualy the association and the models ! You dont need to all these, It seems like you are following a tutorial without understanding it. Your index.js file should me simpler than what you have done:

require your models (const User = require('./models/user'); ... ...), then declare the associations (Post.belongsTo....), than re drow the schema (sequelize.sync().....).

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA It's basically the index.js automatically generated by sequelize command : npx sequelize-cli init. I'm gonna do it as you suggest... the sync command is in the index file, not the app file ?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I followed all your advices and the server started and the tables were created  ! :-)  I'm a bit confused between files index.js and app.js. Do you confirm that I can put associations, sync, in the api app.js file and get rid completely of the index file of the model folder which is not relevant anymore (that's what I did but I was a bit confused, as in your answer you spoke about app and then we spoke about index). Sorry for all these questions, It's a bit hard to find my way between online courses I took, online tutorials, and your advice, lots of concepts to be integrated...

Comment: @GeffSwayze the index.js is used for squelize client (I guess), but yes, you can define associations and then use the sync method directly into the app.js file

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA And the include function... works !!! OMG, I don't know how to thank you for this one !!!